# Statistics of region of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have an array that measures about 2000 elements long, and I would like to figure out the standard deviation of it centered at each pixel by sliding a make-believe window of some relatively small width over it, and computing the StDev of the elements in each region, yielding an array that is the same number of elements as the input. So, if the width was set to 5, the StDev centered at element zero would compute `np.std(arr[0:3])`.

More concretely, let's say your input array was

```
[0.14  0.1  0.12  0.25  0.29  0.17  0.21  0.22  0.16  0.18  0.14]
```

and you wanted a width of 7. For element 0, you'd compute `stdev([0.14  0.1  0.12  0.25])`, for element 2, you'd compute `stdev([0.14  0.1  0.12  0.25  0.29])`, and so on.

It seems a naive solution would be to iterate over the input array and either extend the input array by `floor(width/2)` elements (simply masking out the outer elements on the first and last few pixels), or just modify the width used.

Is there a faster way to do this, especially one that doesn't require repeatedly selecting sub-arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.stats.moments.rolling_std.html).

```
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.random(20)
stds = pd.rolling_std(data, window=7, center=True, min_periods=1)  # min_periods to get the edges
```

Comment: True, but you'll want to add `center=True` in the arguments to have what the OP wanted. And beware the `ddof` (degrees of freedom). +1 very useful and forgot about it.

Comment: This is neat, but when I try it, the last three elements show up as `nan`. Does this also happen for anyone else?

Comment: Make sure you add the ``min_periods=1`` argument, otherwise it will fill in ``nan``s on the edges. And as Oliver pointed out, the ``center=True`` argument is also needed. If you're still having problems make sure you have the latest release (0.15.x).

Comment: Okay, thanks, it looks like my version is likely the issue here, since I've specified `min_periods=1` and `center=True`. The issue can be trivially solved by calling `rolling_std(arr[::-1])`, then replacing the last `floor(window/2)` elements of the original std array with the first `floor(window/2)` elements of the reversed std array.

Comment: BTW, I'm on pandas 0.14.0

Comment: yeah, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0150-roll for the change in v0.15

Answer (score 1):

You could create a very memory efficient view on the array using `stride_tricks`, but that will still not solve your problem of the window at the edges, where the window is "cut-off" or reduced. There, you could consider iterating over the different window sizes. It'll give you a speed boost if the windowsize is much smaller than the array over which you want to compute the standard deviation (or the mean for that matter).

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

a = np.arange(20)
windowlen = 5
assert windowlen & 1  # this method only works for windows of uneven size
b = np.empty(a.shape)
b[windowlen//2:a.size - windowlen//2] = as_strided(a,
    shape=(a.size - windowlen + 1, windowlen),
    strides=a.strides*2).std(axis=-1)

for ind in range(windowlen//2):  # iterate over the edges where the windowsize is reduced
    lim = windowlen//2 + 1 + ind
    b[ind] = a[:lim].std()
    b[-1 - ind] = a[-lim:].std()

# b: array([ 0.81649658,  1.11803399,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,
#    1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,
#    1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,
#    1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.11803399,  0.81649658])
```

As you can see, I've added an assertion, because this idea only works correctly if the window has an odd length. Otherwise, where would you want the `std` of an array with e.g. four elements - at the one with index 1 or the one with index 2?

Comment: this is a neat approach, especially since I can specify an odd-length window right off the bat and just not need the assertion. I'll probably end up using James's solution, simply because it's a little more transparent to me. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: @DathosPachy glad you like it. Indeed, the solution offered in the pandas library is very useful and I'd use it too if I had pandas installed on the machine I'm working on. If someone isn't interested in installing another library, the code above might be just right.

Comment: Yeah, props for using just numpy. I'd have given up without a clean solution like pandas.